# windows phone 8 render rotation not working correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on **Windows Phone 8 C#/XAML .NET 4.5 Application**.

I have a page that has **portrait orientation** (only - I *need* to have the page in this orientation).

On the Page there i a top panel and under it is the rest of the page as content. The content needs to be rotated by **90 degrees** clockwise and the rotated content must fill the rest of the page.

The problem I'm encountering is that **not everything is shown** after I rotate the content by 90 degrees. Even If I set the content to be SQUARE (same width and height) and rotate it around the center by 90 degrees, only the part of what was shown originally that fits on the screen is rendered.

Simplified example:

```
<!-- SIMPLIFIED FOR BREVITY  -->
<page with portrait orientation>
  <Grid x:Name=Content>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="120" /> <!-- TOP PANEL -->
       <RowDefinition Height="*"   /> <!-- REST OF THE CONTENT -->
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <TopPanelControl />


     <!-- I'M working with 480 x 800 page resolution -->
     <!-- for the purpose of simplicity              -->
     <!-- But the page can be any size               -->

     <Grid x:Name="RotatedContent"
             Background="Red"
             RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             Width="668"
             Height="400"
             Grid.Row="1">
             <!-- EVEN IF THE HEIGHT IS 668, result is the same -->
         <Grid.RenderTransform>
           <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
         </Grid.RenderTransform>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Text="000"
                    TextAlignment="Left"/>

         <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    Text="111"
                    TextAlignment="Center"/>

         <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="2" 
                    Text="222"
                    TextAlignment="Right"/>

     </Grid>

  </Grid>
</page>
```

My question is:

**How to rotate a control that is wider than the screen (but not when rotated) by 90 degrees and then SHOW IT WHOLE (unclipped).**

Answer (score 1):

The [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox(v=win.10).aspx) is handy for stretching content.   Wrap the Grid in the ViewBox.

**XAML**

```
<Viewbox  Grid.Row='1'
          Stretch='Uniform'
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
          VerticalAlignment='Top'
          HorizontalAlignment='Right'>

  <Grid x:Name="RotatedContent"
        Background="DarkRed"
        Height='400'
        Width='400'
        Grid.Row='1'
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
      <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    ...
</Viewbox
```

**ScreenShots**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmm, this can be used to achieve the result :) I'm going to try it and post a result/set it as answer after i try :)

Comment: Well, it almost works, the problem is the stretching is done before the rotation, which means that the resulting card is stretched "too much" (the zoom-in is too big) and only small part of it appears on the screen. The clipping is gone though.

Comment: you'll have to play around with the settings on the viewbox and grid.  It works well, when the size is square, my example doesn't work as nice with the content is rectangular.

Comment: that's the problem, i nned it rectangular

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my own problem by using CANVAS control. Canvas control can be bigger than the screen of a phone, but when rotated everything on it is rendered correctly without clipping (the only problem being background). I'm going to finish more comprehensive answer later, don't have time right now.

P.S.: If anyone want to write it before I have time to do it, this answer is here to be edited :)